# Assembly: System Time Printing

Tags: assembly, time, x86

I need to get the system time and print it. The problem is I don't know how to print it. I have a code below, I don't know where I'm wrong. Only the hour part of the time is written below. Thanks! :)

```
pc macro a    
mov ah, 02    
mov dl, a    
int 21h    
endm

cseg segment para 'code'    
assume cs:cseg; ds:cseg; ss:cseg; es:cseg    
org 100h

start: jmp begin
hr db '0'
begin:
mov ax, 03h     ;clear screen
int 10h


mov ah, 2Ch
int 21h
mov hr1, ch
mov bx, 10
mov ah, 0   
mov al, hr1
idiv bx
add al, '0'
add ah, '0'
mov hr, al
pc hr
mov hr, ah
pc hr

int 20h
cseg ends    
end start
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to brew coffee in assembly...

Comment: @Arno: you can start by reading Coffe-HOWTO (http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Coffee.html) on how to connect a coffe machine to your PC.

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for the hint. I like the _Kernel Hackers' Guide_ most.

Answer (score 1):

You've only got code there to print the hour. "idiv bx" doesn't do what the comment says - try "idiv bl". Your macro is trashing ah "behind your back". Fix those and give it another try...

Best,
Frank

Comment: Thanks. It's now working up to the seconds. It's not possible to know the time if it is in AM or PM, right?

Comment: Dunno. Does ch go to 12 or 24? (may take a while to determine this... or screw around with system time)

Comment: Ch is in 24. Thanks. I thought it's not working because when I first tried it, it returns the same value when I just changed the time to PM. What if the returned value is in a 16-bit register, for example in cx, what format of division should I do?